# Extract some files and create some folders with the same name

Tags: python

I have the following problem:
if I have a .zip file, the folders are created, but no data is extracted and placed in the full folder.

```
zipfiles = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('C:/Data/Test/test1/*')]
                 
for zipfile in zipfiles:
                 new_dirname = zipfile.replace('.bin.', '_')
                 try:
                     os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}')
                 except:
                     print(f'output/{new_dirname} already exists')
                 try:
                     os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}/full')
                 except:
                     print(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir already exists')
                     
                 with ZipFile(f'C:/Data/Test/test1/') as zipObject:
                     zipObject.extractall(path=f'output/{new_dirname}/full')
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Right away, I can tell you that `files` is a list, and `files.replace()` should return an error. Did you mean `file.replace()`?

Comment: @B.Pantalone ive edited my question. i fixed this with an str konvert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with ZipFile(f'C:/Data/Test/test1/') as zipObject:`
... is the selecting the folder as a zip object.

I think you need:
`with ZipFile(f'C:/Data/Test/test1/{zipfile}') as zipObject:`

You can do your directory creation in one step, as well. Using [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Now the problem is that I somehow can't get it open. These are bin.XXXX files that I can unzip with 7z but not with the tool, where I get raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
>>>
Is there a way to still unpack these under the procedure?

Comment: Just because 7zip can open the file, doesn't mean it's a zipfile. The python module clearly thinks it's not. You'll have to experiment to find out exactly what compression standard has been used.

Comment: i`ll found out it is a tar type

Comment: So the problem is this are tar files, but I’ve not work with tar files… only with zip.